# Does Structured Buffers has special alignment constraints?

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, directx-12

I am implementing instancing in my renderer. To do so i need to use a StructuredBuffer of mesh data. Here what I first tried:

```cpp
struct MeshData
{
    float4x4 transform;
    uint meshId;
};  

StructuredBuffer<MeshData> meshDatas : register(t0);
```

And **CPP** side:

```cpp
__declspec(align(16)) struct MeshData
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 transform;
    UINT meshId;
};
```

Unfortunatly this doesnt work.  I get gliches in my rendering:
[image]

Instead of:
[image]

Since now I just needed to align CPP structures to 16 bytes to be able to properly send them to the GPU.
But to solve this one I had to add padding on both the CPP code and HLSL. This one worked:

**HLSL**:

```cpp
struct MeshData
{
    float4x4 transform;
    uint groupId;
    float pad1;
    float pad2;
    float pad3;
}; 

StructuredBuffer<MeshData> meshDatas : register(t0);
```

**CPP**

```cpp
struct MeshData
{
    DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 transform;
    UINT groupId;
    FLOAT pad1;
    FLOAT pad2;
    FLOAT pad3;
};
```

Does Structured Buffers has special alignment constraints?

Comment: The `struct` for a structured buffer does not require any byte alignment (unlike a constant buffer). Try removing the `__declspec(align(16))` in your C++ `struct` declaration, and also check the stride size you specified in the shader resource view description.

Comment: Removed the __declspec(align(16) and it works. Dont know how i didnt think about it. Can you write answer please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike constant buffers, structured buffers in D3D12 have no special alignment constraints.

On earlier hardware, however, some vendors did promote 16-byte alignment for performance, but I don't think this has a noticeable impact on modern generations of GPU.

Therefore it's not necessary to byte align C++ `struct` declarations with `__declspec(align(x))`.

If you do include a `declspec` directive, then this may only force you to add unnecessary padding in both the C++ and HLSL `struct` declarations to keep them aligned.